# Parse text that have html inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing

I have the following text

```
let text = "La altura del Monte Everest es <select class='cs-select cs-skin-slide' id='memorySelect'></select> y es por eso considerado el monto más alto del mundo"
```

After adding the select options via JS, I append in my body as this.

```
$('body').html(text)
```

So my result is the following

[image]

That's where the problem is!. Is my string I need the HTML to parse in the **MIDDLE** of the text, **NOT** at the end

So the result would be the following

[image]

Why does the HTML goes down? I tried the same with 3 HTML structures and all 3 goes down and the text remains at the top.

UPDATE:
This is the CSS of the SELECT

```
display: inline;
vertical-align: middle;
position: relative;
text-align: left;
z-index: 100;
background: #292f33;
max-width: 500px;
user-select: none;
```

Comment: works fine in the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9jmn8vwv/ ? My guess is it's based on the CSS formatting of the select element, make sure it's using something like `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Do you have any css in your file? Perhaps your select has `float` set? Using your code as-is, it appears to work as intended: https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/088f8z8b/4/

Comment: Check your CSS, there are some classes on the select that probably cause that.

Answer (score 0):

What does your CSS look like? Is the select element displayed inline? Also consider wrapping your text in `<p>` tags. Because your code without CSS is working as intended:

```js
let text = "La altura del Monte Everest es <select class='cs-select cs-skin-slide' id='memorySelect'></select> y es por eso considerado el monto más alto del mundo"

$('body').html(text)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, the SELECT is displayed inline. I just deleted all CSS just to make a hard test, and the JS is also placing the SELECT at the bottom :/

Comment: @LesterVargas That's strange! What happens if you try something like this: var myHtml = $.parseHTML(text);
$('body').html(myHtml);

Comment: Yep, I also tried that :/ I mean I think I tried every trick I know, that why I post it to see if there was something I'm missing :/